# Existence of a morphism of schemes from $X$ to $\mathbb P_A^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

In exercise **§II.III.VIII.** of [Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199202494) by *Qing.Liu.* one is asked the following:

> Let $X$ be a scheme over a ring $A.$ Let $f_0, \cdots,f_n\in\mathcal O_X(X)$ be such that the $f_{i,x}$ generate the unit ideal of $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ for every $x\in X.$ Show that $X=\cup_i X_{f_i}$ and **that we have a morphism $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb P_A^n$ such that $f^{-1}(D_+(T_i))=X_{f_i}$ and that $f|_{X_{f_i}}$ is induced by the map $g:A[T_i^{-1}T_j]_j\rightarrow\mathcal O_X(X_{f_i})$ sending $T_i^{-1}T_j$ to $f_i^{-1}f_j.$** If $A=k$ is a field and $x\in X(k),$ determine $f(x)$ as well.

That $X=\cup_i X_{f_i}$ is easy, and I think the morphism $f$ comes
from the invertibility of  $f_i$ in $\mathcal O_X(X_{f_i}),$
from the fact that morphisms into an affine scheme are in bijection with ring-homomorphisms of the rings of global sections,
from the composition of the above deduced map with the inclusion $D_+(T_i)\rightarrow\mathbb P_A^n,$
and finally from *the compatibility of these maps.*
`But how could I show the compatibility of these maps?` I am now confused by those entangling relations between morphisms and between schemes, and cannot see how to verify this compatibility.
Also, to determine $f(x),$ first identiy $\mathbb P_k^n(k)$ with $\mathbb P(k^{n+1}).$ Then, for $x\in X(k)\cap X_{f_i},$ we find $f(x)=(\alpha_0,\cdots,\alpha_n),$ where $\alpha_j$ is the image of $f_i^{-1}f_j$ in $k=k(x).$
Any hint or answer is welcomed.

P.S. Please forgive my cumbersomeness in this area, and help me improve upon it, as I am quite unfamiliar with algebraic geometry. Sincere thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the compatibility note that $D_+(f_i) \cap D_+(f_j)=D_+(f_if_j)$ and also $\mathcal{O}_X(X_{f_i}) \cap \mathcal{O}_X(X_{f_j})=\mathcal{O}_X(X_{f_if_j})$.
Now you need to check that if we localize $g_i : A[T_i^{-1}T_k] \to \mathcal{O}_X(X_{f_i})$ at $\frac{T_j}{T_i}$ and $g_j : A[T_j^{-1}T_l] \to \mathcal{O}_X(X_{f_j})$ at $\frac{T_i}{T_j}$ we obtain the same map $A[(T_iT_j)^{-1}T_kT_l] \to \mathcal{O}_X(X_{f_if_j})$.

Comment: Finally I am able to complete this exercise! But I don't know why the second equality holds, and where it is used in the proof: We just need to first verify that the maps $h_i:A[T_i^{-1}T_k]\rightarrow\mathcal O_X(X_{f_i}\cap X_{f_j})$ factorise through the localisation, and then that the induced maps coincide, as indicated in the answer, right? Still thanks.

Comment: You'r right. The point is that the sets $X_f$ are a generalisation of the sets $D(f)$, and like them are very useful and easy to work with.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer again.